# Sortable list in Sencha Touch 2.3 - How do I use it?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I've just installed Sencha Touch 2.3, and I notice there is a new plugin called "Ext.plugin.SortableList":

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.plugin.SortableList

I was in the middle of writing my own sortable list, based on Sencha Touch 2.2.1, when I saw this and thought it was time to upgrade Sencha Touch and use a plugin instead.

Can anyone provide a small example of how to use this? I was hoping it would allow me to specify a handle selector for dragging and use it straight away, but it doesn't seem to work. Code is below. Any help appreciated.

```
Ext.define('kcm.view.favslist', {

    extend: 'Ext.List',

    requires: [

        'Ext.dataview.List', 
        'kcm.store.favstore', 
        'Ext.plugin.SortableList'

    ],

    xtype: 'favslist',      

    config: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',      

        emptyText: 'No favorites. Tap the Add button to add the current topic.',        

        store: 'favstore_id',

        itemTpl: '<table id="each_fav" width="100%" valign="center" border="0"> '+
        '<tr valign="center">'+
            '<td valign="center" width="30"><div>' +
                '<input type="image" name="Delete" id="delfav" src="resources/images/deletebuttonnew.png" ' +
            '</div></td>'+
            '<td><div class="fav_title">{fav_name}</div>' +
                '<div class="fav_breadcrumb">{breadcrumb}</div></td><td valign="center" width="30"><div>' +
                '<input type="image" name="dragfav" id="dragfav" zindex="99999" src="resources/images/dragitem.png" ' +
                '</div>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</table>',

        plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.SortableList',
                handleSelector: 'dragfav'

            }
        ]



    }



});
```

Thanks,

Andy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the handleSelector config should be a CSS type selector, so in your example it should be ".dragFav" to select an element with the dragFav class.